# jquery in partial html, getting rendered in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an RoR application. This has many timezones per user. The timezones database that has many time differences (customized). A user can create any number of timezones and all his timezones are displayed in his homepage. This is achieved by the render timezones in the homepage.

```
<%= render @user.timezones.paginate(page: params[:page]) %>
```

This calls the partial, _timezone.html.erb for each timezone, thus displaying every one of his timezones.

```
<tr>
<td><%= timezone.name %></td>
<td><%= timezone.city %></td>
<td><%= (timezone.positive ? '+ ' : '- ') + timezone.hours.to_s + ':' + timezone.minutes.to_s %></td>
<td><div class="time-rect-container" data-positive="<%= timezone.positive %>" data-hours="<%= timezone.hours %>" data-minutes="<%= timezone.minutes%>"></div></td>
<td><%= link_to "edit", edit_timezone_path(timezone) %> </td>
<td><%= link_to "delete", timezone, method: :delete,
                                   data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>     </td>
</tr>
```

I want to display the current time in each timezones, so I have a jquery for it. My java file :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function () {
 time_div = $('.time-rect-container');
 var dt = new Date();

 var x = time_div.data('hours');
 var y = time_div.data('minutes');
 z = time_div.data('positive') 
 utchours = dt.getUTCHours();
 utcminutes = dt.getUTCMinutes();
 utcseconds = dt.getUTCSeconds();
 if (z == true)
    var time = parseInt( utchours + x + (utcminutes + y) / 60) % 24 + ":" + (utcminutes + y) % 60 + ":" + dt.getUTCSeconds();
 time_div.html(time)
}, 1);
```

});

However, this script is not called for every timezone, so the hours, minutes from the first timezone is passed to the java from div, and the current time of timezone 1, is displayed for all timezones. How can I change this to display current time for each and every timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [Moment.JS](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for time calculation in javascript it is a jquery library. I provides you many helper methods for time calculation.

to loop thorugh all dives you need to call each on `$('.time-rect-container');`

This code can be replaced

```
var dt = new Date();

 var x = time_div.data('hours');
 var y = time_div.data('minutes');
 z = time_div.data('positive') 
 utchours = dt.getUTCHours();
 utcminutes = dt.getUTCMinutes();
 utcseconds = dt.getUTCSeconds();
 if (z == true)
    var time = parseInt( utchours + x + (utcminutes + y) / 60) % 24 + ":" + (utcminutes + y) % 60 + ":" + dt.getUTCSeconds();
 time_div.html(time)
```

With: (pseudo code)

```
$.each($('.time-rect-container'), function(i, time_div){
  var x = time_div.data('hours');
  var y = time_div.data('minutes');
  z = time_div.data('positive') 

  if z == true
     var time = moment.utc().add(x,'h').add(y,'m'); // can be moment.utc().add({hours: x,months: y})
  time_div.html(time._d)
})
```

Comment: I would still need to pass the time difference for every timezone, how do I do that?

Comment: Yes, I agree. But that would still leave my problem unsolved. I would get the timezone added to only my first timezone and not all timezones.

Comment: keep this `.time-rect-container` this class in every div